# Numeric index during batch insertion in Neo4j

Tags: java, indexing, numeric, neo4j, batch-insert

I'm using batch insertion of nodes and relationships into Neo4j graph database. Everything works, including the index on multiple properties `([String] name, [int] id)`. However, when I try to query the index on property "id" by range, it returns no results.

The problem, as I derived it from [the non-batch example](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/indexing-lucene-extras.html#indexing-lucene-numeric-ranges), is that I can't supply numeric `ValueContext` to the `BatchInserterIndex` like so:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);

properties.put("name", urs.getString(1));

// I can do this:
properties.put("id", urs.getInt(2));

// But not this (throws an "invalid type" exception):
// properties.put("id", new ValueContext( urs.getInt(2) ).indexNumeric());

long node_id = inserter.createNode(properties);
index.add(node_id, properties);
```

I haven't found any [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/indexing-batchinsert.html) regarding numeric indexing during batch insertion.

The query code is as follows:

```
IndexManager index = gdb.index();
Index<Node> people = index.forNodes("people");
IndexHits<Node> hits = people.query(
    QueryContext.numericRange("id", min_id, max_id)
  );
```

Is it at all possible to add numeric index in a batch insertion operation, so that I can then query values by range?

Thanks.

---

### Edit

What I was doing wrong is I tried to pass the same property map to `createNode()` and `index.add()`. The former was crashing, because it doesn't need `ValueContext` and doesn't understand it. So, be sure to pass different property maps to these methods and include `ValueContext`-ed numeric value in the one meant for `index.add`:

```
Long value = 1L;

long node_id = inserter.createNode(
  MapUtil.map("id", value, "other_prop", other_value));

index.add(node_id,
  MapUtil.map("id", ValueContext.numeric( value ), "other_prop", other_value));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of neo4j are you using? It's working in the latest release

Comment: The version is neo4j-community-1.4.1, which is the latest. Are you sure you're getting range results by employing **batch** insertion index? If so, can you be more specific, please? Did you manage to pass the `ValueContext` to the batch inserter index?

Comment: Could you look at the test: https://github.com/neo4j/community/blob/master/lucene-index/src/test/java/org/neo4j/index/impl/lucene/TestLuceneBatchInsert.java#L282 , that seems to be very similar and it passes.

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll append the description of my error in the post. Thanks.